# How can use df.appen when I use eval

Tags: python, pandas, eval

j=88.87

I wnat to use eval to do like this:

```
data_88_87=data_88_87.append(data[data['norm']==88.87])
```

but:

```
eval('data_'+str(j).replace('.','_'))=eval('data_'+str(j).replace('.','_')).append(data[data['norm']==j])



File "<ipython-input-110-a69e45d994b1>", line 5
    eval('data_'+str(j).replace('.','_'))=eval('data_'+str(j).replace('.','_')).append(data[data['norm']==j])
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

```
eval('data_'+str(c).replace('.','_')+'='+('data_'+str(c).replace('.','_')).append(data[data['norm']==j]))


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-64d2b5d27c76> in <module>()
----> 1 eval('data_'+str(c).replace('.','_')+'='+('data_'+str(c).replace('.','_')).append(data[data['norm']==2.98]))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

How can use df.appen when I use eval?

Comment: Check the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as follows:

```
j = 88.87
tempVar = "data_"+str(j).replace('.','_')
globals()[tempVar] = eval(globals()[tempVar]).append(data[data['norm']==88.87])
```

The above code will give you following output:

```
data_88_87=data_88_87.append(data[data['norm']==88.87])
```

Comment: Hi,
globals()[tempVar] = eval(globals()[tempVar]).append(data[data['norm']==88.87]) have error

Comment: globals()[tempVar] =globals()[tempVar].append(data[data['norm']==88.87]) is correct